# jQuery.get() using a function in the php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax with jQuery and I'm trying to use a function the php rather that the file.

My current code

**jQuery**

```
$.get("ajax2.php", function(data){ 
    $('#textbox').html(data);          
});
```

**php**

```
<?php              
 ..php code       
 echo $theData;   
?>
```

How do I update my jQuery.get() function call a function in the php rather than the file.

```
<?php              
function test()   
{                 
 ..php code       
 echo $theData;   
}                 
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand you clearly, but if you're trying to get jQuery to run a PHP function, or PHP to run a jQuery function -- you can't. One is client-side, the other is server-side, and there simply is no way to intersect the two.

Comment: @mblase75 I can think of at least 2 ways to do what you say  is impossible, and this guy is on the right track. Think about calling the page with some GET or POST parameters with the name of the function you want to call, and use a switch statement to execute and return data from only the function you want.

Comment: @Relic Then by all means, post an answer. It's possible I'm just not understanding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mblase75 The answer is blow... Make the ajax call to something like:

```
<script>
$.get("ajax.php?command=dance", function(data){
    $('#textbox').html(data); 
});
</script>

//------PHP(ajax.php)--------
witch($_GET['command') {
   case 'delete':
       delete_record();
       break;
   case 'dance':
       cut_a_rug();
       break;
   default:
       return;
}
function cut_a_rug(){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript cannot call PHP functions directly. They're two utterly different environments. You'd need to create a simple web service API to allow external agents (e.g. javascript) to call things in PHP.

e.g

```
<?php

switch($_GET['command') {
   case 'delete':
       delete_record();
       break;
   case 'dance':
       cut_a_rug();
       break;
   default:
       return;
}
```

And "call" the functions by hitting appropriate urls:

```
 http://example.com/yourscript.php?command=delete&id=42
 http://example.com/yourscript.php?command=dance&type=waltz
```